# How to get the value of specific index inside an array column using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

[image: This is my database table]

```
$reports = DB::table('attendance_report_details')
            ->select('*','project_hours[$index_id]')
            ->get();
```

I am passing index id to the function. Is there a way to do it like this?

Comment: [Possibly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html). But why are you storing your data in a non-relational format like this?

Comment: I am storing the data as json ecoded data

Comment: I know you are, I can see that. My question was _why_ are you doing it like that, rather than creating a proper relational structure?

Comment: Because the project hour is related to a corresponding project.The sequence of project may differ for each att_rep_id.Also, old projects may be deleted. So its needed to store it like this.

Comment: None of that stops you from making a proper structure using separate tables and foreign keys. If you did that you could have many-to-many relationships linking the employee table to the project table via a project hours table which stores the hours, and foreign keys to the employee and projects tables. Then writing queries to get particular hours is trival using SQL. Maybe you first need to study database design in more detail if you didn't realise this kind of thing?

Comment: I have created this table for reference only.It cannot be linked to any tables.I am saving the old data to this table so that even if we make any changes in old data, the data in this data wont be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the arrow operator (MySQL-only):

```php
$reports = DB::table('attendance_report_details')
    ->select('*', DB::raw("project_hours->'$[".(int) $index_id."]'"))
    ->get();
```

Or its alias `JSON_EXTRACT()` (MySQL & MariaDB):

```php
$reports = DB::table('attendance_report_details')
    ->select('*', DB::raw("json_extract(project_hours, '$[".(int) $index_id."]')"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Nope.. :( I am getting an error. For the first solution the error is            
 "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$[1]' from `attendance_report_details`' at line 1"

Comment: For the second solution: json functions can be used only in mariaDB version 10.2.3 and above . My version is 10.1.36. I am using xampp

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your answer :) @Jonas Staudenmeir